# jQuery UI number spinner event question

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, jquery-ui

I've been stumped on this problem for over a week :(  Any insight into this problem would be hugely appreciated!

How do I link a jQuery UI number spinner/stepper (http://wiki.jqueryui.com/Spinner) so that a label text value changes as the spinner value increments or decrements?

```
    ...
        <script type="text/javascript">


                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $("#s1").spinner({max: 100, min: -100});

                    $("#s1").bind("spin", function() {
                      $("label1").innerText = $("#s1").spinner("value");
                    });
                });
        </script>
    ...

<body>
...
    <p><label for="s1">Basic:</label> <input id="s1" name="value"/></p>
    <p><label for="label1"></label></p>
...
</body>
```

Thanks!

Edit:  In addition to the output issue, there appears to be problem with the handler itself.  The handler doesn't execute when I spin/change the spinner.

Comment: <label for="label1"></label>
shouldn't this be id="label1"?
$("#label1").html($("#s1").spinner("value"));

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've modified the question above since the handler doesn't seem to be executing in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the UI/Spinner documentation, the name of the spinner change event is not "spin", but "spinchange". If you change the parameter of the .bind method accordingly, things should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - from your sample above I changed your label to a span so the text would have somewhere to go, used this.value inside the spin handler, and jQuery's .html() to dump the value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#s1").spinner({max: 100, min: -100});

            $("#s1").bind("spin", function() {
              $("#label1").html(this.value);
            });
        });
</script>

<body>
  <p><label for="s1">Basic:</label> <input id="s1" name="value"/></p>
   <p><span id="label1"></span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post.  I tried this however I'm still unable to get the it working.  I think there is also an issue with the event handler itself since it doesn't appear to be executing when I change the spinner. Thanks.